# Python - Performing Max Function on Multiple Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame below that shows the price of wood and steel from two different suppliers.

I would like to add a column that shows the highest price for the opposite item (i.e. if line is wood, it would pull steel) from the same supplier.

For example, the "Steel" row for "Tom" would show his highest wood price which is 42.

The code I have so far simply returns the highest price for the original item (i.e. not the opposite, so for Tom's steel row returns 24 but I would have wanted it to return 42).

I think this is an issue with pulling the max value for a multi-group. I have tried a number of different ways but just cannot seem to get it.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Supplier':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Bill','Bill','Bill'],'Item':['Wood','Wood','Steel','Steel','Steel','Wood'],'Price':[42,33,24,16,12,18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Opp_Item'] = np.where(df['Item']=="Wood", "Steel", "Wood")
df['Opp_Item_Max'] = df.groupby(['Supplier','Opp_Item'])['Price'].transform(max)
print(df)


  Supplier   Item  Price Opp_Item  Opp_Item_Max
0      Tom   Wood     42    Steel            42
1      Tom   Wood     33    Steel            42
2      Tom  Steel     24     Wood            24
3     Bill  Steel     16     Wood            16
4     Bill  Steel     12     Wood            16
5     Bill   Wood     18    Steel            18
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the per supplier+item maximum, then you can just swap the values and assign them back through a `join`:

```
v = df.groupby(['Supplier', 'Item']).Price.max().unstack(-1)
# This reversal operation works under the assumption that
# there are only two items and that they are opposites of each other. 
v[:] = v.values[:, ::-1]  

df = (df.set_index(['Supplier', 'Item'])
        .join(v.stack().to_frame('Opp_Item_Max'), how='left')
        .reset_index())

print(df)
  Supplier   Item  Price  Opp_Item_Max
0     Bill  Steel     16            18
1     Bill  Steel     12            18
2     Bill   Wood     18            16
3      Tom  Steel     24            42
4      Tom   Wood     42            24
5      Tom   Wood     33            24
```

Note: Ordering of your data will not be preserved after the join.

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` to the opposite values before a groupby, and then merge this back to the original DataFrame.

```
d = {'Steel': 'Wood', 'Wood': 'Steel'}

df.merge(df.assign(Item = df.Item.map(d))
           .groupby(['Supplier', 'Item'], as_index=False).max(),
         on=['Supplier', 'Item'],  
         how='left',
         suffixes=['', '_Opp_Item'])

  Supplier   Item  Price  Price_Opp_Item
0      Tom   Wood     42              24
1      Tom   Wood     33              24
2      Tom  Steel     24              42
3     Bill  Steel     16              18
4     Bill  Steel     12              18
5     Bill   Wood     18              16
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This results in a number of my other columns creating new _Opp_Item columns. Any idea how to limit this just to the Price column?

Comment: @tgile512 Subset the `DataFrame` you merge to just the three columns, item, price and Supplier